# How can I connect to multiple organization and projects from Azure Devops tool to PowerBI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi

I connected to Azure DevOps Boards using personal access token to fetch workitems by referring to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops
I was able to connect to only one organization and one project under that at a time.

I have a requirement in which I need to connect to multiple organizations and projects and fetch all work items under that.

Please advise how can I go about accomplishing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to connect to multiple organizations and projects and fetch all
>   work items under that.

You can try with combining `OData` and `Manage Parameters` in Power BI to achieve what you want. This is the new feature we provided last month. Just refer to and follow this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-cross-organization-reporting-and-analysis-using-power-bi/) description.

This blog has provided very detailed steps on how should we do. The nutshell of this feature is using `Parameters` to automatically have a report to create filter, then it will load a data model from azure devops, here our azure devops OData can provide this data model. This `Parameters` can let users generate a report, and providing values for its Parameters.

Hope this blog is help.